# Automatic (API) posts to Facebook does not get any views/attention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website for which I use Facebook's API (GraphAPI) to post to my Facebook-page. I have about 5.000 followers on the FB page and ususually get some 1.000 views per (manual) post. However, if I post to the Facebook page using the API I only get 1 view and I am pretty sure that is just my own view - i.e. it is invisible for other users. The post is set as Public (it has that globe icon).

My guess would be that my API login to the website is not an administrator and is thus just shown as if any user would post on the page. The name of the "person" posting to the Page is not my private name, but my app name. I don't recall allowing my API to specifically post to the FB-page so this seems logical in some way.

I believe the problem is likely to be related to administrator rights issues or the likes of it but in case it has to do with the technical stuff, here we go:

Technically, I use Ruby on Rails and the Koala gem. At https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer I have a specific App (i.e. not GraphAPI) and then I use a page access token to push my content to the Facebook-page. I do this using the "app secret" with the command:

```
my_api_client.put_connections("me", "feed", message: "my message")
```

Strictly, technically, this works but the posts does not seem to be visible for others.

What do I need to do? What settings should I be looking into?

Comment: I would guess your app is not public

Comment: Seems logical. What does it mean that the app is not public? Where do I edit this, in that case?

Comment: Go to developers.facebook.com/apps . Click on the app and then Review and Status I believe. There is a big switch on top of that page

Comment: Ah, I see! I missed that menu selection. I thought it had to do with sending a review (like 5 stars) about my thoughts of the app. It was set as "under development" there so I will try it out.

Comment: WizKid. It seems that you were right - for the first time I get that "This has been seen by 55 people". Thanks! Please put it as the answer and receive your reward :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You app must be live.

Go to developers.facebook.com/apps . Click on the app and then Review and Status I believe. There is a big switch on top of that page